# .push() multiple objects into JavaScript array returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I add items to the beats array and then console.log the User, I'm getting the correct number of items in the array. But when I check .length, I always get 1. 
Trying to call the index will always give me 'undefined' like so:
`Tom.beats[1]`
I think I'm missing something obvious, but this is beating me. I suspect that I'm misusing the `.push` method but I'm unsure. Any help is greatly appreciated!
(using Chrome dev tools)

```
//The USER

function User(name, role){
    this.beats = [ ]; 

    this.name = name;
    this.role = role;

    // add beats to beats array

    this.addBeats = function(beats){ 
        return this.beats.push(beats);
   };

}

// Three New Instances. Three New Users.

var Mal = new User("Mal", "Rapper");
Mal.addBeats(["love", "cash"]);

var Dan = new User("Dan", "Producer");
Dan.addBeats(["cake", "dirt", "sally-mae"]);

var Tom = new User("Tom", "Producer");
Tom.addBeats(["Fun", "Little", "Samsung", "Turtle", "PC"]);

// Check for position in beats array

console.log(Tom.beats); 
console.log(Mal.beats); 
console.log(Dan.beats); 

console.log(Mal.beats[1]);
console.log(Dan.beats[1]);
console.log(Tom.beats[1]);
```

Comment: I wonder if the `this` pointer is getting confused in the addBeats function. Can you step-through it in a JS debugger? (IE9 has one).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[`Array.push(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) takes multiple arguments to append to the list. If you put them in an array itself, this very array of "beats" will be appended.

[`Array.concat(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is most likely not what you are looking for, because it generates a new array instead of appending to the existing one.

You can use [`[].push.apply(Array, arg_list)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to append the items of the argument list:

```
this.addBeats = function(beats) { 
    return [].push.apply(this.beats, beats);
};
```

Comment: Using your, method, it works how I intended now. Thanks! So, my return  line was totally incorrect...

Comment: `[].push` will create a new array each time a function is called. I guess it’s cheaper to use `return this.beats.push.apply(this.beats, beats)` instead.

Comment: @AlexanderKachkaev, actually, no: http://jsperf.com/nil-push/2. Using `[].someFunction.call`, `{}.someFunction.apply`, etc. is a pattern that at least Firefox and Chrome understand and optimize. Using `[].push`, instead of `variable.push` or `Array.prototype.push` is a little faster, since it won't involve a lookup for the variable name.

Comment: @Kay it'd be nice of jsperf gave a profile of the memory consumption as well.  The additional fraction of a percentage performance benefit might be offset by garbage collection deferred to a later time?  (This kind of optimization might explain why Gmail takes up more RAM than my Java IDE if I leave its tab open for a few days?!)

Comment: Note: one year later my statement is not true anymore. `Array.prototype.push.apply` is by 10% or so faster in Firefox v44 and Chrome v46.

Answer (score 11):

#### Spread operator

In environments that support the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) you may now do the following:

```
this.addBeats = function (beats) {
    return this.beats.push(...beats);
};
```

Or if you need more control for overwriting etc

```
this.addBeats = function(beats) { 
    return this.beats.splice(this.beats.length, null, ...beats);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

addBeats() should concat this.beats with the beats parameter.