# Short way to replace content of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, underscore.js

Is there any convenient way to replace the content of an array, AND keep a reference to it? I don't want to replace the array like this:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var referenceToArr1 = arr1;
var arr2 = [4,5,6];

arr1 = arr2;
// logs: [4,5,6] false
console.log(arr1, arr1===referenceToArr1);
// logs [1,2,3]
console.log(referenceToArr1);
```

This way `arr1` has the content of `arr2`, but I loose the reference in `referenceToArr1`, because it still points to the *original* `arr1`.

With this way, I don't loose the reference:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var referenceToArr1 = arr1;
var arr2 = [4,5,6];

arr1.length = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  arr1.push(arr2[i]);
}
// logs: [4,5,6] true
console.log(arr1, arr1===referenceToArr1);
// logs: [4,5,6]
console.log(referenceToArr1)
```

The drawback here is, that I have to empty `arr1.length = 0`, iterate over every element of `arr2` and push it to `arr1` by hand.

My questions are:

- Sure, I could write a helper for this, but what is the most efficient way?
- Is there a short, vanilla javascript way, to do this (maybe a one liner?)
- I'm also using underscore.js but haven't found a method for this kind of problem. Is there a way to do this with underscore.js?

**Background:**

I have an AngularJS app with a service. Inside this service, I have an array to keep all the elements loaded from the server. The data from the service get's bind to a controller and is used in a view. When the data from the service get's change (e.g. a refetch happens), I want to auto update my controllers vars and the view it is bind to.

**Here is a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8yYahwDO6pAuwl6lcpAS?p=preview**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  myService.fetchData().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    $scope.data = data;
  })
});

app.service('myService', function($timeout, $q) {
  var arr;
  var deferred;

  var loadData = function() {
    // here comes some data from the server
    var serverData = [1,2,3];
    arr = serverData;
    deferred.resolve(arr);

    // simulate a refetch of the data
    $timeout(function() {
      var newServerData = [4,5,6];
      // this won't work, because MainCtrl looses it's reference
      // arr = newServerData;
    }, 1000);

    $timeout(function() {
      var newServerData = [7,8,9];
      arr.length = 0;
      [].push.apply(arr, newServerData);
    }, 2000);

    $timeout(function() {
      var newServerData = [10,11,12];
      [].splice.apply(arr, [0, arr.length].concat(newServerData));
    }, 3000);
  }

  return {
    fetchData: function() {
      deferred = $q.defer();

      loadData();

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
})
```

And the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="d in data">{{d}}</li>
    </ul>
    3 refetches every second
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript

Comment: @elclanrs this is exactly the opposite I want to achieve. They are copying arrays into new arrays. I want to replace the content of one array with another array without creating a new array.

Comment: My intuition tells me this is an XY problem. Why do you need to mutate an array, or a variable like that? What is the real-world use case?

Comment: I added some background information and a plunker. I think this is a real world use case, isn't it?

Comment: @23tux I just have to confirm: it is real world case! ;) had to solve almost the same... and the `arr1.length = 0` *(in fact something like `arr1.clear()`)* is the trick which solved lot of similar stuff for me

Comment: So it seems there's no workaround other that mutation, that's unfortunate, but good to know for reference.

Comment: Yes, it would be cool, if angularjs would provide some functionality built in to handle this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about this:

```
// 1. reset the array while keeping its reference
arr1.length = 0;
// 2. fill the first array with items from the second
[].push.apply(arr1, arr2);
```

See:

1. [How to empty an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1234337)
2. [.push() multiple objects into JavaScript array returns 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075651/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to replace the content of `arr1` with the one of `arr2` :

```
[].splice.apply(arr1, [0, arr1.length].concat(arr2));
```

This way, all references to `arr1` would be correctly updated as this would be the same array with a new content.

As you see, that's possible and easy. But there's normally no reason to do this in a well designed program. If the reason is that you're passing an array to different places, then perhaps you should consider embedding this array in an object.

Comment: Another question: What do you think is more efficient? Your solution or the other one from Radim Köhler?

Comment: Probably the one of Radim but it doesn't matter (it you think it matters, profile), that's why I choose to answer with the one that could be written as a one-liner. I like one-liners...

Comment: In ES6 this can be written as `arr1.splice(0, arr1.length, ...arr2)`

Answer (score 0):

This will merge both arrays persisting items from second array

```js
[...arr2, ...arr1.slice(arr2.length)]
```